# Brocade ADX 1000 load balancing: Can't reach the VIP

Tags: brocade, load-balancer

Weird.
We just got a Brocade ADX 1000 for server load balancing.
Config is setup to emulate the basic load balancer configuration in their guide (real servers, VIP and management IP are all members of the same subnet).
Yet we can't ping or reach the VIP at all, with Layer 3. We can arping it to know that it's there.

Is this restricted by licensing (just found out the licenses are circa 2013 and 2014) or is there something wrong with our configuration? I would be grateful for any pointers.

Our basic configuration:

```
    !
server real prod-web01 192.168.72.11
 port http
 port http keepalive
 port http url "GET /status.html"
 port ssl
 port ssl keepalive
 port ssl url "GET /status.html"
!
server real prod-web02 192.168.72.12
 port http
 port http keepalive
 port http url "GET /status.html"
 port ssl
 port ssl keepalive
 port ssl url "GET /status.html"                                  
!                                                                 
!                                                                 
server virtual prod-webVIP 192.168.72.13                       
 predictor round-robin                                            
 port http                                                        
 port ssl sticky                                                  
 bind http prod-web01 http prod-web02 http                  
 bind ssl prod-web01 ssl prod-web02 ssl   
!
vlan 1 name DEFAULT-VLAN by port                                  
!                                                                 
aaa authentication web-server default local                       
enable telnet authentication                                      
enable super-user-password .....                                  
no enable aaa console                                             
hostname lb01                                                   
ip dns domain-name mng.dom                                        
ip dns server-address 8.8.8.8 192.168.71.3 192.168.71.4 192.168.71.5
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.72.1                             
!                                                                 
no telnet server                                                  
username admin password .....                                                                    
no snmp-server enable traps locked-addr                           
no web-management ui-history-collect                              
!                                                                 
interface management 1                                            
 ip address 192.168.72.253 255.255.255.0                          
!                                                                 
interface ethernet 1                                              
 ip address 192.168.70.70 255.255.255.0                           
!                                                                 
access-list 10 permit any
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.
Apparently I am not supposed to add the VIP to the network the mgmt1 interface is on.

Had to use the dsr method in order to get the load balancing to function.
Can't complain but I would have like to do it without dsr (having to create loopback interfaces on the real servers, with the VIP's address).